# Why is my element not a node ? Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, nodes

From a `foreach` I am creating a few `p` elements and putting them into a `div`. I want to be able to drag and drop them.

This is my script to deal with drag and drop

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    function allowDrop(ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
     ev.dataTransfer.setData("text",ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
     var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
     ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
```

This is my script to create my elements and add properties to them.

My `lienClient` list contains an array of object.

With `lien.lien` I am getting a string that I put into my `p` element on loop

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    lienClient.forEach((lien) => {
      var x = document.createElement("div");
      var y = document.createElement("p");
      var z = document.getElementById("liensUrlClientBody");

      x.setAttribute("ondrop", "drop(event)")
      x.setAttribute("ondragover", "allowDrop(event)")
      x.setAttribute("height", "550px")

      y.setAttribute("draggable", "true")
      y.setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)")
      y.innerHTML = lien.lien

      x.appendChild(y)
      z.appendChild(x)
    })
```

[My HTML Elements when my script loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKTsK.png)

I cannot drag my `p` element inside the div of the other `p` element.

[Error in console when I try to drag one of my `p` element to my `div` element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyCcb.png)

I tried to check `nodeType` on my `<p>` elements which returns 1 : If the node is an element node, the nodeType property will return 1.

I tried draging my `<p>` element into another random `div`. Same problem

Can someone explain to me what I am missing with Node elemnts and Node ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: And please present a proper [mre] of the issue, when asking this kind of question. Right now, the part of the code where the error actually occurs, doesn't even appear to be included here.

Comment: @CBroe sure I will edit and quote the error and my DOM.
Just to know why is this question down voted ? Is it because of the images thing ? 
Everytime I get timed out and cant ask anymore questions, I am trying to post only well thought ones now, but there are lot of rules and I dont want to get timed out again

Comment: Have you read [ask] ...? Both the issue with the images, and that we need a proper MRE, are mentioned in there. That what you shown so far is _not_ a proper MRE, should be pretty obvious right away, it starts with the fact that we don't even know what your `lienClient` contains, or - more importantly - what your event handler functions actually do.

Comment: @CBroe ye I did read it already, but I see your point, will do better. Any idea tho ?

Comment: The error is likely coming from this line, `ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))` - which means `document.getElementById(data)` hasn't found anything.

Comment: I am guessing it probably has to do with the event handlers being assigned as  `"drop(event)"` - that will be relying on the global `event` instance, and that might not be the _correct_ event here. I would suggest instead of assigning a code string via `setAttribute`, you go and do that part via `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: @CBroe See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#event_handler_attributes). The `event` variable in an `onXXX` attribute will be the same as the argument to a listener assigned with `addEventListener()`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to give the `<p>` an ID. Instead of using the "on..." attributes you can just have an event listener for the entire list (`div.card-body`).

When you drop, make sure that the parent element is the `<div>`, not another `<p>`.

```js
const cardbody = document.querySelector('div.card-body');

cardbody.addEventListener('dragstart', ev => {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
});

cardbody.addEventListener('dragover', ev => {
  ev.preventDefault();
});

cardbody.addEventListener('drop', ev => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  let div = ev.target.closest('div');
  div.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
});
```

```css
div.card-body {
  display: flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  gap: 1em;
}

div.card-body > div {
  min-height: 6em;
  background-color: gray;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <div height="550">
    <p draggable="true" id="id1">test.fr</p>
  </div>
  <div height="550">
    <p draggable="true" id="id2">testtest.com</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you dropped this ---> 